# How to send traps in local subnet

Tags: c, net-snmp, snmp-trap

I am using Net-snmp. I want to send traps in my subnet. I am having IP of my m/c as 10.0.2.15. I want to send it in 10.0.2.0/24 subnet. I have tried command as follows
snmptrap -v 2c -c public 10.0.2.0/24 "" OID-value pairs

It was getting hanged and resulting into following error

getaddrinfo: 10.0.2.0/24 Temporary failure in name resolution
snmptrap:

Can you please tell me how to send traps in subnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think sending traps in subnet is not possible. Sending trap to particular destination having IP is allowed.

Comment: More importantly, why would anyone send traps to a whole subnet? The purpose of SNMP traps is to notify a network manager about something that happened on a host. An alert of some error, usually, but could be a normally occurring event, too. I struggle to make up a use case for having an entire subnetwork of network managers, all responsible for supervising one host. Normally, traps need to be sent to one or several network managers on well-defined IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your script(i.e snmpd.conf file) and add a line

**trap2sink "IP address you want to connect to":"port"**

at /usr/local/share/snmp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).